# Combinatorics and logic equivalences

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I've seen the following question and I wondered about whether or not the change I did is valid, the question is:

"For how many numbers $i$ when $1 \leq i \leq 120$, the following statement holds:

'if $i$ is not divisible by at least one of the numbers 3,5 then is divisible by 7' "

Can I use the logical equivalence that says : $p \rightarrow q \equiv \lnot p \lor q$ ?

And to substitute the statement into "$i$ is divisible by 3 and 5 or divisible by 7" ?.

I'll appreciate any help !

Comment: my interpretation - if $i$ is not divisible by at least one of the numbers $3, 5$ then is divisible by $7$ would mean count all numbers divisible by $7$ as long as they are not divisible by _both_ $3$ and $5$.

Comment: Yeah correct, what you've said leads to the same answer it looks to me like it's equivalent to what I've said

Comment: There are $17$ numbers divisible by $7$. Out of which, there is only one number $105$ which is divisible by both $3$ and $5$. So that leads to $16$ numbers.

Comment: @MathLover But the implication you wrote would also be vacuously true for any number divisible by both $3$ and $5$, whether or not it is divisible by $7$.

Comment: @KevinLong my statement starts with "...would mean count all numbers divisible by $7$..."

Comment: @MathLover Maybe I misinterpreted what you meant. Are you saying to count only the $16$ numbers you described? That wouldn't include the numbers for which the implication "if $i$ is not divisible by at least one of the numbers $3$, $5$, then $i$ is divisible by $7$" vacuously holds.

Comment: @KevinLong that is correct. That is what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If $i$ is not divisible by at least one of the numbers 3,5 then is divisible by 7"

Can I use the logical equivalence [...] to substitute the statement into "$i$ is divisible by 3 and 5 or divisible by 7"?

No, this is not logically equivalent.

"Not divisible by at least one of 3 or 5" means "(not divisible by 3) and (not divisible by 5)", and negates to "divisible by 3 or divisible by 5".

Comment: But it looks like the opposite to me, I mean if 'i' is not divisible by at least one of them we can say that it is "not divisible by 3 or not divisible by 5", which it's negation seems for me to be "divisible by 3 and 5 both" ,can you see where my logical failure is?

Comment: I mean if a number is not divisible by 3 and divisible by 7 then the original statement is true, and according to what you've said it's seems to be false

Comment: If a number is divisible by 3 but not by 5 or 7, then the original statement is true, but your attempted negation is false (take 6 for example).

Comment: And what you said about my version is not accurate; if a number is divisible by 3 then it is "divisible by 3 or divisible by 5".

Comment: Your logical failure is that "not divisible by at least one of them" means in english that **neither** divides, while "not divisible by 3 or not divisible by 5" means that they do not **both** divide. (**caveat**: "not divisible by at least one of them" does border on ambiguous, but I think my interpretation here is the most likely/common way this would be used)

Comment: Thanks alot, I can understand now where my logical failure is!
So we can say that the statement is equivalent to "divisible by 3 or divisible by 5 or divisible by 7" ?

Comment: Well after I pondered a while, it still seems to me that maybe there is an ambiguity here and the problem isn't well defined, because if we look again at the example you gave (the number 6) then we could say that the statement "6 is not divisible by at least one of the numbers 3 or 5" could be either true or false, because 3 is divisor of 6 and 5 isn't divisor of 6, so from one side it seems to be false (3 isn't divisor of 6) and from the other side it seems to be true (6 is not divisible by 5) so probably this question isn't good one..